# unbuffer/expect swallows the rcode when its child is signaled

Tags: shell-script, signals, expect

`unbuffer` is able to pass along the return code of a process under normal circumstance, but if the process you are unbuffering is killed, for instance with a segfault, I see `$?` as `0` while I expect `139`.  How can I get it to pass along the `139`?

e.g. if I `unbuffer` a  bash script that has simply `exit 1`, I get `$?` as `1`.  If I unbuffer a bash script that has `kill -11 $$`, I get `0`.

`unbuffer` is actually just an `expect` script that comes with `expect`, but I don't know it well enough to decifer why the return code is not passed along.

Comment: I think i figured out why unbuffer doesn't work, but it requires writing a new wrapper. I don't think it can work as is.  The expect wait command returns more arguments if the spawned process is killed but unbuffer just always returns the 3rd argument.  I added a check to see if the 4th arg is CHILDKILLED to at least propigate a non-zero exit code in that case and that is enough for my purposes

Comment: You should provide an answer to your own question, and accept it.